# Vuetify 1.0.0 Tabs with VueRouter not working as expected

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

I am having troubles making vuetify tab work with vue router, here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/jayas/pen/zRVZMo), am i missing something so obvious?

**Purpose**

To render the component for the specified route as part of the tab content itself. In this case would want **Page 1**  t0 appear under tab1 and **Page 2** to appear under tab2. *Clicking on tabs should not redirect me to that route, but rather the content of that route being displayed under each tab*

**packages**

```
 "dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.2",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vuetify": "^1.0.0",
  },
```

**vue-markup**

```
 <div id="app">
 <v-tabs left color='grey lighten-4'>
   <v-tab>Page 1</v-tab>
   <v-tab-item :to="{path:'/page1'}">
   </v-tab-item>
   <v-tab>Page 2</v-tab>
   <v-tab-item :to="{path:'/page1'}">
   </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>
<router-view />
</div>
```

**js**

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)
 let component1 = {
  template:`<div class="title">Page 1</div>`
 }
 let component2 = {
  template:`<div class="title">Page 2</div>`
 }
let router = new VueRouter({
 routes: [
  {
    path: '/page1',
    name: 'Page 1',
    component: component1,
  },
  {
   path: '/page2',
   name: 'Page 2',
   component: component2,
  }
  ]
})

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue too. This setup worked for me.

```
<v-tabs fixed-tabs>
    <v-tab :to="{path:'/page1'}">Page 1</v-tab>
    <v-tab :to="{path:'/page2'}">Page 2</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

So basically don't use `v-tab-item` and instead put the `:to` on the tab.

Comment: a) This wouldnt even render the tabs appropriately. You re welcome to modify my codepen. 
b) Also the content of the tab must be rendered below the tab and not redirect me to the route.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - for the latest versions of Vue and Vue-Router at least.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-tabs left color='grey lighten-4'>
      <v-tab to="/page1">Page 1</v-tab>
      <v-tab to="/page2">Page 2</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-app>
</div>
```